# UIScrollView cannot call addSubview for another UIViewController

Tags: ios, uiscrollview

i have 3 controller

1. first controller load list data (success) --> SearchViewController
2. second controller load detail content with OZDetailTestViewController in third controller --> OZDetailSearchViewController
3. third controller --> OZDetailTestViewController

my problem is, when i call some function in OZDetailSearchViewController (createViewAtIndex) UIScrollViewController cannot load, but log is print when i NSLog in OZDetailTestViewController.
i think _scrollDetailNews cannot alloc, but i don't know how to alloc that.

this is my code:

OZDetailSearchViewController.h

```
@interface OZDetailSearchViewController : UIViewController<UIWebViewDelegate, UIScrollViewDelegate>
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIScrollView *scrollDetailNews;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *viewForScroll;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *lblLineKanal;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *imgHeader;

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSArray *arrAllNews;

@property int indexPageNews;
@property NSUInteger idNewsKanal;
@end
```

OZDetailSearchViewController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    _lblLineKanal.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:20/255.0 green:130/255.0 blue:255/255.0 alpha:1.0];

    _currentIndex = _indexPageNews;
    GCPagedScrollView* scrollView = [[GCPagedScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 80, self.view.frame.size.width, 954)];
    scrollView.delegate = self;
    self.scrollView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    for (NSUInteger index = 0; index < _arrAllNews.count; index ++) {
        //You add your content views here
        [scrollView addContentSubview:[self createViewAtIndex:index]];

    }

    [self.view addSubview:scrollView];
    [scrollView setPage:_indexPageNews animated:YES];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
}

- (UIView *)createViewAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index {
    boxDetailTest = [[OZDetailTestViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"OZDetailTestViewController" bundle:nil];
    _scrollDetailNews = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 107.0, 320.0, 415.0)];
    [_scrollDetailNews setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320.0, 463.0)];
    [_scrollDetailNews addSubview:boxDetailTest.view];
    _scrollDetailNews.delegate = self;
    [boxDetailTest test:index];
    return boxDetailTest.view;
}
```

OZDetailTestViewController.h

```
@interface OZDetailTestViewController : UIViewController
-(void)test:(NSUInteger)index;

@end
```

OZDetailTestViewController.m

```
#import "OZDetailTestViewController.h"

@interface OZDetailTestViewController ()

@end

@implementation OZDetailTestViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
}

-(void)test:(NSUInteger)index{
    NSLog(@"%@",@"sini");
    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 20)];
    label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"test %u", index];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a IBOutlet for scrollDetailNews so I assume that you must have created a scroll view in you storyboard/XIB. But then you are again overriding the same variable (_ scrollDetailNews) in createViewAtIndex method but not adding it back to the main view. Remove this line

```
_scrollDetailNews = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 107.0, 320.0, 415.0)];
```

And instead just use self.scrollDetailNews. If you want to change the frame of the scroll view directly do that:

```
CGRect newFrame=CGRectMake(0,0,0,0); //fill in correct values
self.scrollDetailNews.frame = newFrame;
```